# fread segfault with 30GB space separated file with some rows starting with space

Tags: r, data.table

I was previously able to successfully load a 2.7 million by ~3000 odd column file into R data.table however now I am getting a segfault. The size of the file is still similar. Not sure what might be happening. The error message is not helping either. The machine has enough memory ~256 Gb

```
>   dosages <- fread(combined_dosage_file, header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)

 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'unknown'

Traceback:
 1: fread(combined_dosage_file, header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

SessionInfo()

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.10
```

**Verbose output operating on a smaller test file with 500K lines**

```
> f <- "../common_input/test.dosage"
> d <- fread(f, header=F, skip=1, stringsAsFactors=F, verbose=T)
Detected eol as \n only (no \r afterwards), the UNIX and Mac standard.
Using line 2 to detect sep ('skip' has been supplied) ... sep=' '
Found 3053 columns
First row with 3053 fields occurs on line 2 (either column names or first row of data)
'header' changed by user from 'auto' to FALSE
Count of eol after first data row: 500000
Subtracted 1 for last eol and any trailing empty lines, leaving 499999 data rows
Type codes: 03033222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 (first 5 rows)
Type codes: 03033222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 (+middle 5 rows)
Type codes: 03033222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 (+last 5 rows)
Bumping column 3 from INT to INT64 on data row 193249, field contains 'rs12218882'
Bumping column 3 from INT64 to REAL on data row 193249, field contains 'rs12218882'
Bumping column 3 from REAL to STR on data row 193249, field contains 'rs12218882'

 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'unknown'

Traceback:
 1: fread(f, header = F, skip = 1, stringsAsFactors = F, verbose = T)
```

**Update**

I was looking at the data file more carefully and it turns out some random lines had extra space in  the beginning. After removing those I was able to load the whole file in R (pretty amazing compared to std data.frame) with 60Gb RAM. For now I am good to go but it might be worth exploring if that was the root cause but seems like that space confused the fread to diff col size. May be it can spit out more specific error if feasible.

-Abhi

Comment: Great, thanks for the edit! If the 30GB file now loads fine then the problem can't be the size and must be those spaces at the start, which I can believe for a space separated file. I've filed [bug #5259](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5259&group_id=240&atid=975).

Comment: This issue is now [#494](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/494) on the new github project page. I've just pushed fixes to `fread()` involving space. Could you please upgrade, test and write back? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**Update Sep 2015** : As per @Arun's comment above to question, he fixed this in v1.9.6 on CRAN Sep 2015, [#494](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/494).

---

Previous answer for posterity ...

I've looked through NEWS for v1.8.11 and I can't see any crash fixes for `fread`. In fact I don't remember any outright crash reports for `fread` at all, so this is new.

Please pass `verbose=TRUE` to `fread` and see if you can reproduce with that on.  The output will give me a clue as to where the crash is. It will also report information about the file (rows, columns and types) which will be helpful.

If you start with a fresh session and load the file, does it ever crash?

Btw, iiuc it's going to be between 30GB and 60GB in RAM, depending on the column types (`2.7e6 * 3000 * 4|8 / 1024^3`).  A big file,  but as you say you have 256GB of RAM,  so yes this is definitely something `fread` should be fine with. It's possible `fread` hasn't been tested to this size yet. Datasets of that size mostly tend to be broken down into smaller files and then the idiom is :

```
rbindlist(lapply(<files>, fread))
```

But you have what you have : one very big file.  So `fread` should be fine with it.  Just explaining why it may not have come up before.

Comment: added the verbose output .. I am sort of confused. Data table worked beautifully on the same dataset before and now it is giving me strange errors ..Appreciate your quick help